# Blob data selected from <input file> on ios safari would expire after 1 minute

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari, blob

The problem is once you select an image from the file manager, and use it after one minute, an error would occur.
I have searched for a long time but no result.
Could anyone provide a document or tell me how to address this situation?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Image preview example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div><img style="width:200px;height:200px" id="uploadPreview" src="" alt="Image preview" />
  <input id="uploadImage" type="file" name="myPhoto" />
  <button onclick="loadImageFile()">Save</button></div>
  <div id="error"></div>
  <script>
  oFReader = new FileReader(), rFilter = /^(?:image\/bmp|image\/cis\-cod|image\/gif|image\/ief|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/pipeg|image\/png|image\/svg\+xml|image\/tiff|image\/x\-cmu\-raster|image\/x\-cmx|image\/x\-icon|image\/x\-portable\-anymap|image\/x\-portable\-bitmap|image\/x\-portable\-graymap|image\/x\-portable\-pixmap|image\/x\-rgb|image\/x\-xbitmap|image\/x\-xpixmap|image\/x\-xwindowdump)$/i;

oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
  document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
  document.getElementById("error").innerText='';
};

oFReader.onerror = function(error){
  document.getElementById("error").innerText=error.toString();
}

function loadImageFile() {
  if (document.getElementById("uploadImage").files.length === 0) { return; }
  var oFile = document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0];
  if (!rFilter.test(oFile.type)) { alert("You must select a valid image file!"); return; }
  oFReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
}
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

HELP!!!

Comment: How about some code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ You need to provide the code for other contributors to help you. This link provides guidelines on how to create a Minimal Reproducible Example in your post >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Interesting... I don't have access to an iOS device to test on my hands, so could you try [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/36xct9dm/) and [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/36xct9dm/1) and let me know what got reported after the timeout passed.

Comment: Hi Kaiido, they both say three failures

Comment: ... That's pretty bad actually, I never thought they would automatically revoke a blob URI... Could you also try these ones [1](https://jsfiddle.net/L17uymvp), [2](https://jsfiddle.net/L17uymvp/1/)?

Comment: I have to say again three failures. BTW, the code you provide cannot run on safari until I find elements first and change oninput to onchange :)